# Running a program after compiling it with javac

Tags: java, compilation

I have a source file named `Plane.java`. I am trying to compile and run the program in terminal, but i can't!

I am compiling it with:

```
javac Plane.java
```

So, I am getting with `ls` my classes

```
   CargoBay.class
   CleaningEmployee.class
   Employee.class
   EquipmentComponent.class
   MaintenanceEmployee.class
   PassengerComponent.class
   Plane.class
   Plane.java
   PlaneComponent.class
   PrivateComponent.class
   SecurityEmployee.class
```

Now, I have no idea how to run it! I am trying with `java Plane`, but I keep getting errors. Any ideas ?

(errors: after `java Plane`)

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Plane (wrong name: plane/Plane)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

The program runs just fine in netbeans

Comment: Learn to use ant, maven, or gradle. It's a waste of time to fight with java commands at command-line.

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting in command line.

Comment: but my university needs me to give em the compile command

Comment: What error  you getting while executing `java Plane` command ??

Comment: The error you get is a runtime exception. It happens when trying to **run** the program. The command you gave us is used to **compile** the Plane.java source file. What is the command used to run the program. What is the code of Plane.java (from the very first line)?

Comment: @bmargulies He said it runs fine in netbeans, so that is covered.

Comment: You need to execute the command from very same directory where you Plan and other class reside means first `cd` to that the class directory.

Comment: @bmargulies: I don't think it makes sense for someone lerning Java to use these tools. And by the way,  I have wasted lots of time trying to get ant scripts running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile your class by

`javac -d . Plane.java`

This will create a plane directory at current location and put your classes into that directory then run your program using

`java plane.Plane`

Comment: You defined your class with package i.e. `package plane;` (first line of your program). It means your `Plan` must be placed inside a folder named `plan` so we used `-d` java-option to auto-create plan directory and while running the program since class is present inside the directory so we executed `java plan/Plan` (i.e. Plan class in the plan directory)

Comment: @HakiTerror: You should learn about packages and how they are related to directories. Also try to find out what the classpath is.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are probably in a package named plane. The compiler creates a directory with the package name. What you have to do is go up one level from there
and call:

```
java plane.Plane
```

Other options would be to set the CLASSPATH environment variable or use the -cp option of the java command.